# Spring 3.0 annotation bean Component Scan

Tags: java, spring-3

How to do `component-scan` in spring 3.0? I use annotation like @Service, @Reponsity for both jar and project. It does not work. When the bean in project inject from the bean in jar.

In jar file

```
    com.java.spring.support
```

In project

```
    org.me.project
```

My configuration is

```
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.java.spring.support, org.me.project"/>
```

In Jar File

```
    package com.java.spring.support;

    @Service("CommonService")
    public class CommonService {
    }
```

In project

```
    package org.me.project;

    @Service(value = "OtherService")
    public class OtherService {
        @Resource(name = "CommonService")
        private CommonService service;
    }
```

I get error

```
    15:41:53,043 DEBUG [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.sprin
    gframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@510ebe18]
    15:41:53,044 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'CommonService' is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:529)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1095)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:277)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
        at org.ace.java.support.delete.Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5315069/106261

Answer (score 0):

Use only `<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.spring.support, org.me.project">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository"/>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.me.project"/>
```

You are using an exclude filter on repository annotations, remove it.

Comment: @CycDemo thats how you specify annotation based config; what exactly is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @CycDemo ok, show the declaration of bean named 'CodecHandler'. And why are using a main method in delete.Test ? Show the code for that too

Comment: @CycDemo you have not shown the code that is causing the error. That is test.Main and CodecHandler;also bean id should start with lowercase, the java camelCase convention.

Comment: I already change `CodecHandler` to `CommonService`. Actually it is actually happen.